# jQuery validation not working when using ASP.NET button

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

I use jQuery for form validation. When the user doesn't fill out the form he get the message "some fields required".  This works if I have a input button, but when I change this to asp:button to postback the webpage and the validation doesn't work.

How can I to solve this problem?

many thanks.

code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">    
    $().ready(function()
    {         
    var validator = $("#aspnetForm").bind("invalid-form.validate", function() {         
       }).validate({
        errorElement: "em",
        errorContainer: $("#warning, #summary"),
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.appendTo( element.parent("td").next("td") );
        },
            rules: {
              <%=TextBoxCodigo.UniqueID %>: {required: true}
                  },
            messages: {
                <%=TextBoxCodigo.UniqueID %>:{required: "Requerido"}
                }
        });

         $('#btnGuardar').click(function () {
            var txtUsuario = $('#<%= TextBoxCodigo.ClientID %>').val();
            if(validator.form())
             {            

                    $.msg({content: "valido"});

             }else{$.msg({content: "El formulario tiene " + validator.numberOfInvalids()   + " errores.<br> Por favor vea los detalles indicados."});}
        });
    });

    </script> 



    public void btnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        BoClassCodigo boClassCodigo = new BoClassCodigo();
        boClassCodigo.CodigoDescripcion = TextBoxCodigo.Text;
        boClassCodigo.Sesion = new BoClassSesion();
        boClassCodigo.Sesion.Sesiones = (Int64)((Usuario) Session["uSession"]).Sesion;
        boClassCodigo.Sesion.Terminal = ((Usuario)Session["uSession"]).Usuario;
        string cad = BllClassCodigo.InsertarCodigo(boClassCodigo,conexion);

    }
```

Comment: Can you post some code samples.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your jQuery is looking at the wrong ID.

If you have an asp button like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnOne" runat="server" />
```

Your jquery code needs to look at:

```
$('#<%= btnOne.ClientID %>')
```

Comment: if I do it, I cant see the button in the webpage.

Comment: What do you mean you can't see it?  What does your asp button definition look like?

Comment: the button in runtime cant be viewed in the webforms, this occurs when I remove the runat="server" tag. <asp:Button ID="btnGuardar" Text="Button" /> if I use runat="server" tag, the button fire a postback and jQuery validation dont work. :(

Comment: Post your jquery validation code, you're likely doing someething wrong within the validation.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it seems You should enable the Client Side Validation or Disable the Client Side Validation based on whether you want a postback to happen or not.

It is always recommended to use Validations on both the Client and Server for better security.